# How much space is allocated on the stack

Tags: c

I am solving one test question and I am not sure with correct answer. The question is: If I run the code under 32bit OS, how much space will be allocated on stack in moment when we return from function malloc() in function hook(). There is also assumption that all required memory was assigned.

[Here is code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJpus.jpg)

```
…char A[1000000]…

int hook() {char C[2000000]; …
    ptr_char2 = (char) malloc (5000000)); /*Hi guys, how much memory do I have now?*/……
}

int main() {
    char B[3000000];……
    ptr_char = (char*) malloc (4000000));
    hook();…
}
```

I know that on the stack are stored statically allocated variables. Dynamically allocated are on the heap. I tried to count char A(0.9MB) + char B(1.9) + char C(2.8) and it takes around 5.6MB. However the correct answer is one of the following 1MB, 5MB or 9MB. Could someone help me where I am doing mistake? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are supposed to include the code *verbatim* in the question, please edit accordingly, thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. This website keeps questions and answers so they can be useful for other people in the future. To that purpose, you are required to post the actual code and not a link to it or an image of it.

Comment: OK, I just put there screenshot of question, but I tried to edit it. Sorry.

Comment: As the code will never compile, the stack will never be used cause there is no program to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` is static and so is not on the stack.

At its ultimo depth, `main` is called and `hook` is called. So at that point both `B` and `C` are on the stack.

That makes a total of 5000000 bytes = 4.76837158203125 MB.

Comment: Yeah, so the correct answer will be 5MB. And where is stored char A? Thanks.

Comment: `A` is stored in the BSS segment, which is not the stack segment nor the heap segment. Lookup "BSS" for more information.

Comment: Are there any pointer variables in stack? `ptr_char` and `ptr_char2` aren't defined in the functions, but of course it's also not shown that they'd be static... Not that it matters to the end result with those choices, though.